# Notice: Array to string conversion (SQL Server and PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, database

I got this error when i try to fetch an array of data.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in line 7
```

However, it only happens with some tables. I can fetch the data from the other table but not these three :

**USER**

- EmployeeId (nvarchar) PK
- uName (nvarchar)
- uDept (nvarchar)

**TRANSACTION_PO**

- POId (int) PK
- StockId (int) FK
- EmployeeId (nvarchar) FK
- PODate (date)
- POVendorName (nvarchar)

**TRANSACTION_SO**

- SOId (int) PK
- StockId (int) FK
- SODate (date)
- SOQuantity (int)
- SOCustomer (nvarchar)

And this is my code :

```
require_once 'connection.php';
require_once 'session.php';

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_PO";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET )) OR die(sqlsrv_errors()); // LINE 7 (ERROR)

    echo
    '<table id="t01" width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" border="1">';


if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{


    echo
    '<tr>
    <td><div align="center">' . $row ['StockId'] . '</div></td>
    </tr>';

}
echo "</table>";
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I've tried fetching data from other tables and it works fine. I've tried everything but never seemed to get an answer why. Really need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything and i found an answer :

from this

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_PO";
```

should be like this

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM [MRS].[dbo].[TRANSACTION_PO]";
```